# How to submit a Rails form with JQuery or Javascript when an input changes using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

```
  <%= form_with(model: deal, remote: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.check_box :approved %>         
    <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>

function init(){
  $( "table select, table input" ).on( "change", function(e) {
    $(this.form).trigger('submit.rails');
  });
}
```

When I click on the submit button, it works as expected. The form is submitted and the page is ***not*** refreshed.

But when using JQuery it refreshes the page.

`e.preventDefault();` did not help.

Rails 6.0

Comment: Thats a really vague selector and might come back to bite you if there ever are any more forms on the page like a search form, I would suggest adding a class to the form and using that to make the selector more specific.

Comment: are you getting html request or js request while sumitting form using jQuery?